# Can I force JPA/Hibernate to include the ORDER BY clauses in the SELECT statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My company has developed a convenient system for generating dynamic queries (filtering, sorting, pagination). It ends up sending a `Specification` and `Pageable` to a JPA Repository and the repo figures out the full query. It has been working great for a number of years.

Recently I updated it to be able to filter on properties of child entities (`@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`). However, when I did so I needed to force the generated query to be distinct, otherwise, the join table may produce duplicates. This works great if you only filter, but if you filter & sort on any @OneToOne or @ManyToOne child properties then there is an SQL error.

```
Order by expression "HEADERCHILD3_.ID" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement:

SELECT DISTINCT
    header0_.HEADER_ID                 AS HEADER1_4_,
    header0_.COL_STATUS_ID             AS COL_STA10_4_,
    header0_.CREATED_BY                AS CREATED11_4_,
    header0_.PRIORITY_ID               AS PRIORIT16_4_,
    header0_.REQUESTED_COMPLETION_DATE AS REQUESTE5_4_,
    header0_.RESOLUTION_ID             AS RESOLUT17_4_
FROM
    DBO.REQUEST header0_
INNER JOIN
    DBO.XREF_REQUEST_CHILD child1_
ON
    header0_.HEADER_ID=child1_.HEADER_ID
INNER JOIN
    DBO.CHILD headerchild2_
ON
    child1_.DIVISION_ID=headerchild2_.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    DBO.CHILD headerchild3_
ON
    header0_.PRIORITY_ID=headerchild3_.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    DBO.CHILD headerchild4_
ON
    header0_.COL_STATUS_ID=headerchild4_.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    DBO.CHILD headerchild5_
ON
    header0_.SL_STATUS_ID=headerchild5_.ID
WHERE
    header0_.HEADER_ID=4
AND (
        headerchild2_.ID IN (14 , 13 , 30))
AND (
        header0_.CREATED_BY=10
    OR  header0_.COL_STATUS_ID<>4)
ORDER BY
    header0_.REQUESTED_COMPLETION_DATE ASC,
    headerchild3_.ID ASC,
    headerchild4_.SHORT_TEXT ASC,
    headerchild5_.SHORT_TEXT ASC,
    header0_.HEADER_ID ASC 
limit ?
```

So the ORDER BY clauses are not automatically included into the select clauses by JPA. Is there a way to force them to be included? Is there some JPA "magic" that I am just missing?

**Edit 1** 
So if I can't tell JPA to do it, can I just overload `SimpleJpaRepository`'s method `getQuery()`

```
@Override
protected <S extends T> TypedQuery<S> getQuery(Specification<S> spec, Class<S> domainClass, Sort sort) {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<S> query = builder.createQuery(domainClass);

    Root<S> root = applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, domainClass, query);
    query.select(root);

    if (sort != null) {
        query.orderBy(toOrders(sort, root, builder));
        if (query.isDistinct())
        {
            List<Selection<?>> selections = new ArrayList<>();
            selections.add(root);
            for (Order o : query.getOrderList())
            {
                Selection<?> s = o.getExpression();
                selections.add(s);
            }

            query.multiselect(selections);
        }
    }
```

**Edit 3**
This seems like it should be the solution except I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.a.b.domain.Header].
Expected arguments are: com.a.b.domain.Header, 
org.joda.time.LocalDate,
long,
java.lang.String,
java.lang.String,
long
```

I don't think I should have to create specific constructors as I don't have to do so for "normal" JPA operations. But when I do create appropriate constructors for each possible dynamically generated sort, it appears to work appropriately. **So how do I get rid of the need to create the constructors?**

**Edit 4**
Indeed this is not scalable. For dynamic sorting you need to create all possible constructors (ordering of parameters is important), ballpark estimate is no more than 2^N constructors... where N is number of properties you want to sort by. It is smaller than that since you can remove "duplicate" constructors that have the same parameter type lists and you can sort the sorters...

for instance making

```
public Header(String s1, LocalDate d1) {}
public Header(LocalDate d1, String s1) {}
```

equivalent. But still, this is a large number of constructors.

Comment: I never had to create custom constructors using criteria api.... Stop using selection and you should be fine. I have no idea why would you make selection list dependant on sort order. (Or other way around)

Comment: Apparently using multiselect is what is requiring the constructors. Again, because it is a distinct query, MS SQL server requires that the sort terms also be in the select clause. So then we are back to the original question, how do we get the sort fields in the select clause.